# Output Build Order of Visual Studio solution to a text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

Is there a way to output the Build order to a text file via command line?

To explain: We use multiple branches of source and have large solutions of 100+ projects on each branch. I need to write build scripts to build these solutions from command line. We can then tailor the solutions on the branches to only have project references for the projects that team are working on. This should greatly increase solution load time and ease the frustration of the Developers and me, I hope :)

I'm going to keep looking and maybe look at using C# and the APIs provided with VS. We are using 2012 update 1.

Comment: Can you just do a rebuild, copy the compiler output and process that? I don't have Visual C# handy to see if that works.

Comment: Yes. that would work. I can set the verbosity to minimal and grab the output and parse it for project names. But I was hoping there was a more elegant and repeatable way to solve this as this may be something we will have repeat in the future.

Comment: The build order is defined by the project dependencies that are stored in the solution file. If you want to get the build order on your own, you need to analyze the solution file and the project dependencies.

Comment: Say project A and project B have no dependencies between them, and the compiler is currently building them in the (arbitrary) order A,B. If someone introduces a dependency later, such that A now depends on B, a solution containing all of the projects will "just work" and re-order the build. But, of course, your command line build will not and each build of A will always be based on a slightly out of date build of B.

Comment: Damien, I guess this is something to keep in mind. We have a previous incarnation of this process using a command line build. When dependencies are changed it is up to the person who changes the dependency to change the build script. If the plugin idea below works however, I may add a job to the CI environment to regenerate the build order and check against existing list. That way the CI job will fail if the buildorder has changed or needs updating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good candidate for a Visual Studio Plugin project.

1. Create a new **Visual Studio Add-in** project.
2. In the project creation wizard make sure you choose the following configuration in the **Choose Add-in Options** step (the other steps are not important, I'm assuming you'll use C#):

[image]

2. In the *Connect.cs* file, add the following fields:

   ```
   private BuildEvents _buildEvents;
   private Events _events;
   private bool buildEventConnected = false;
   ```
3. And add / modify these methods accordingly:

   ```
   public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
   {
       _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
       _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;
       _events = _applicationObject.Events;
       _buildEvents = _events.BuildEvents;

       if (connectMode != ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_UISetup && !buildEventConnected)
       {
           _buildEvents.OnBuildDone +=
               new _dispBuildEvents_OnBuildDoneEventHandler(BuildEvents_OnBuildDone);
           buildEventConnected = true;
       }
   }

   private void BuildEvents_OnBuildDone(vsBuildScope Scope, vsBuildAction Action)
   {
       const string BUILD_OUTPUT_PANE_GUID = "{1BD8A850-02D1-11D1-BEE7-00A0C913D1F8}";
       TextDocument txtOutput = default(TextDocument);
       TextSelection txtSelection = default(TextSelection);
       Window vsWindow = default(Window);
       vsWindow = _applicationObject.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindOutput);
       OutputWindow vsOutputWindow = default(OutputWindow);
       OutputWindowPane objBuildOutputWindowPane = default(OutputWindowPane);
       vsOutputWindow = (OutputWindow)vsWindow.Object;
       foreach (OutputWindowPane objOutputWindowPane in vsOutputWindow.OutputWindowPanes)
       {
           if (objOutputWindowPane.Guid.ToUpper() == BUILD_OUTPUT_PANE_GUID)
           {
               objBuildOutputWindowPane = objOutputWindowPane;
               break;
           }
       }
       txtOutput = objBuildOutputWindowPane.TextDocument;
       txtSelection = txtOutput.Selection;
       txtSelection.StartOfDocument(false);
       txtSelection.EndOfDocument(true);
       objBuildOutputWindowPane.OutputString(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
       txtSelection = txtOutput.Selection;
       var solutionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(_applicationObject.Solution.FullName);
       System.IO.File.WriteAllText(solutionDir + "\\build_output.log", txtSelection.Text);
   }

   public void OnDisconnection(ext_DisconnectMode disconnectMode, ref Array custom)
   {
       if (buildEventConnected)
       {
           _buildEvents.OnBuildDone -= new _dispBuildEvents_OnBuildDoneEventHandler(BuildEvents_OnBuildDone);
           buildEventConnected = false;
       }
   }
   ```

That's it, on every build you'll have the output sent to the `build_output.log` file in your solution's folder.

Comment: Will give the plugin a go. Need a bit of time to test, haven't built one since vs 2008 days and that seemed complicated at the time! will come back with results! Thanks!

Comment: Alex, many thanks for the code. This is what I was looking for. I've tweaked it a little and now have more ideas (you've opened pandoras box for me!).

Comment: And is there a way to do that with newer versions of VisualStudio like VS2017 ?

Answer (score 7):

Quick way is to do a "Clean Solution" so that you can see the inverted order in build log.